# RoR Update attributes of children upon deletion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my RoR app, i have the following relationship: A team has many players, players belong to a team.

What i want to do is change the value of the player's column `team_id` to '10' (free agent) when that player's team gets deleted. Here's what my `teams` model looks like, which isnt working

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :players, :after_remove => :make_free_agents  

  def make_free_agents(player)
    player.update_attribute(:team_id, "0")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

[Association callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#label-Association+callbacks) only get triggered "when you add an object to or remove an object from an association collection". If you want the player's attributes to be updated after deleting the team, I'd recommend using the [`after_destroy` hook](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) on the Team class instead.

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_destroy :make_free_agents
  has_many :players

  def make_free_agents
    players.update_all(team_id: 0)
  end
end
```

Comment: Hmm.. When i do this, i get the error `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)` when trying to destroy a team

Comment: I've edited my answer to fix the mistaken bit. Apparently after_destroy callbacks don't get a record parameter (unlike before_save/after_save, etc.)

Comment: you sure that wont update every player, regardless of team? Where would it know to only update the specified team's players?

Comment: Within the scope of the after_destroy callback, `this` is set to the team instance being destroyed. So, the `players` collection will be appropriately scoped as well.

Answer (score 1):

The following code in my team model did the trick:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_destroy { |record| Player.update_all("team_id = '0'", "team_id = #{record.id}")   }
  has_many :players



end
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a distinction between "delete" and "destroy." If you're actually using "delete" no callbacks will run.

So if you want the code to run either way, your best bet is probably a trigger written in SQL. If your data store supports it.

Otherwise your own solution looks fine.